# How to read the @Request Param attribute values that contains ampersand (&) in Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Team,

When i try to read the Request Param attribute values that contains ampersand (&) in spring Boot rest api i am getting Number Format Exception. Below is sample code which i tried. Please Suggest me on this.

Request URL : http://loacalhost:8080/search/ad?skey="uc"&fn="M&M"

Rest Controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search/ad")
public ResponseEntity<List<SearchResultDTO>> findSearchResult(
            @RequestParam(value="skey",required=true) String skey,
            @RequestParam(value="fn",required=false,defaultValue = "null") String fn
            ) {
.....
}
```

Exception is :   "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "M&M""

I tried below ways also :

fn="M%26M" , fn=""M%26amp;M" , fn=""M&M" in each case below was the exception i am getting.

"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "M%26M"",    "M%26amp;M""    "M&M""

As suggested i tried below .

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SearchIntegrationTest {

```
@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Autowired
TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

@Test
public void findearchResult_IntegrationTest() throws JSONException {

    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("/search/ad").queryParam("skey", "uc")
            .queryParam("pf", "C&S").encode().toUriString();

    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());

}
```

}

Error is: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C%26S"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@GetMapping("/example")
public Map<String, String[]> getExample(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameterMap();
}
```

And the URI would be:

```
?skey="uc"&fn="M%26M"
```

And the response in JSON format

```
{
    "skey": [
        "\"uc\""
    ],
    "fn": [
        "\"M&M\""
    ]
}
```

You also can extract the single parameter if you know it's name by using

```
request.getParameter("skey");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do URL encoding when sending the request. If you are testing the API manually, then you have to encode it yourself.

eg.

```
http://loacalhost:8080/search/ad?skey="uc%26fn%3D%22M%26M"
```

Else if you are using RestTemplate to test this API, then you can use something like this:

eg.

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUriString("http://loacalhost:8080/search/ad")
        .queryParam("skey", "uc&fn=\"M&M").encode().toUriString();
new RestTemplate().getForEntity(url, String.class).getBody();
```

Comment: No, I tried in swagger UI  for testing purpose and tried get api call in browser url.

Comment: then you have to manually encode those ampersand(&) , equals (=) and quotes (")

Comment: Srry Abhinaba, small change in request uri, I have updated Request Url and also tried encoded way still issue occurring.